# Sharepoint 2013 JSLink TaskList custom item rendering with out of the box options

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, tasklist

I was not able to find the way to customize SP2013 Task List item rendering with JSLink in order to completely change the way that list item is rendered BUT also keeping all out of the box functionalities provided by default.

I mean, I'd like to display list elements as colored boxes, but also keeping sorting options, "..." (Open Menu) icon etc.

How can I achieve it? Is there any documentation where I can find lists of all internal fields like PercentComplete etc. which rendering can be overriden?

Any code snippets would be really appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look [here](http://www.estruyf.be/blog/create-a-task-progress-bar-with-js-link-in-sharepoint-2013/)

In a nutshell, what you want to do is, on the `Templates` object in the override context object add an object that is called `Fields`. In this object attributes named the same as the static name of a column(field) are used for rendering the value using the 'View' attribute. So, the example from the link is:

```
var overrideCtx = {};
overrideCtx.Templates = {};
// Override field data
overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
    // PercentComplate = internal name of the % Complete
    // View = you want to change the field rendering of a view
    // <div ... = here we define what the output of the field will be.
    'PercentComplete': { 'View' : '<div style="background: #F3F3F3; display:block; height: 20px; width: 100px;"><div style="background: #0072C6; height: 100%; width: <#=ctx.CurrentItem.PercentComplete.replace(" %", "")#>%;"></div></div>' }
};
// Register the override of the field
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx
```

Using this method you will retain the default functionality in the other fields. Just make sure the column is visible in the current view.